# Run seed from subfolder cakephp

Tags: cakephp, migration, subdirectory, seed

I am trying to run seeds from a **subfolder**, like:

App/src/config/Seeds **(default folder)**

I want to run on App/src/config/Seeds/MyFolder

with this command, I run seed from the default folder:
./dev cake migrations seed --seed FileNameSeed

Answer (score 0):

Per the examples [in the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/migrations/2/en/index.html#seed-seeding-your-database), just specify the `--source`, relative to the project root, like so:

```
cake migrations seed --source config/Seeds/MyFolder --seed FileNameSeed
```